# how to print '\n' only last character in C while loop?

Tags: c, while-loop

I want to print a '\n' at the end of the sentence.

just like

> Hello my friend
>
> Yo Hi

and here is my code

```
while(scanf("%c",&b)!=EOF)
{
if((b>=97&&b<=122)||(b>=65&&b<=90)||b==32)
printf("%c",b);

printf("\n");
}
```

but it dosn't work.

should i add a conditional to print '\n'

it may like

```
if(last character)
printf("\n");
```

but i don't know how to do that

Comment: define end of sentence, maybe you should include '\n' (10) as accepted char code

Comment: oh that 's a great idea

Comment: If just reading single characters then `scanf` is overkill. Use e.g. [`fgetc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgetc) instead: `int b; while ((b = fgetc(stdin)) != EOF) { ... }`

Comment: By the way, if you decide to use newline as the "end of sentence", then you don't need any special casing, just print the character whatever it is.

Comment: Do you think writing `97` and `65` makes a better program than writing `'a'` and `'A'`?

Comment: @PvzAKho: Have you tried this? `if (b == '\n') { printf("\n"); }`

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you don't *know* when the last character happens, at least not *inside* the loop. So the simple solution to your problem is to just move the printing of the newline out of the loop.

Comment: but i need to input more then one sentence and i hope in the end of every sentence can print  a '\n'

Comment: @PvzAKho Then you need to define how a sentence ends.